# Python Mechanize: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'f' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, mechanize

I am a beginner at python and I am trying to use the mechanize module for web scraping, but for some reason it keeps telling me that I reference local variable 'f' even though I have no such variable.

Here is my entire current script:

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open('https://hac.friscoisd.org/HomeAccess/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fhomeaccess%2f')
```

If I use the exact same code and replace the link with 'https://stackoverflow.com', it works, but with the link that I need to use, I get the error message:

```
Exception has occurred: UnboundLocalError
local variable 'f' referenced before assignment
   File "C:\Users\colin\MyPythonScripts\mechanizeGPA.py", line 3, in <module>
      br.open('https://hac.friscoisd.org/HomeAccess/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fhomeaccess%2f')
```

Please help!

Comment: Python mechanize is long dead. You want to use Requests for this.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll check that out

Answer (score 0):

You could try unquoting the url before sending to the library

```
>>> import urllib
>>> url = "https://hac.friscoisd.org/HomeAccess/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fhomeaccess%2f"
>>> url = urllib.parse.unquote('https://hac.friscoisd.org/HomeAccess/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fhomeaccess%2f')
>>> url
'https://hac.friscoisd.org/HomeAccess/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=/homeaccess/'
```